# Defining a two part environment using minted and listings

Tags: listings, minted

I am writing some programming instructions for students, and I am trying to format the code so that it looks like the cell input/output structure of a Jupyter or Google Colab notebook.  So I want it to look something like

[image]

So far I've been using the minted package to get the code because I like its automatic syntax highlighting and the listings package because it looks like the output of a notebook.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} %%to make a framed environment

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}


\usemintedstyle{xcode}

\definecolor{light-gray}{rgb}{0.789035,0.789035,0.789035}
\setminted{bgcolor=light-gray}


\lstset{frame=b,
  language=Python,
  aboveskip=-2mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily}
}

\newminted{py}{linenos=true,
autogobble,
python3=true,
obeytabs=true,
tabsize=3,
frame=none,
framesep=10pt}


\begin{document}


\begin{pycode}
print("Hello world!")
\end{pycode}
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello world!
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This looks good for the most part, except when LaTeX does weird things with spreading the vertical spacing out on a page, it separates the minted environment from the listings environment vertically.  I would like to combine these into one environment to force them to stay together.

I know that I can combine environments together like

```
\newenvironment{doubleproof}{
    \newcommand{\nextpart}{\end{proof} \begin{proof}}
     \begin{proof}}{\end{proof}}
```

so that

```
\begin{doubleproof}
First proof
\nextpart
Second proof
\end{doubleproof}
```

produces

[image]

However, when I try defining

```
\newenvironment{cell}{
    \newcommand{\nextpart}{\end{pycode}\begin{lstlisting}}
     \begin{pycode}}{\end{lstlistings}}
```

and using it in a similar way, I get an error.  Is there a way to get this to work, or another solution to formatting my output like this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm quite confident that you could switch to a `minted`-only solution, i.e. that you could produce the 'output' also with `minted`. You may want to look into `tcolorbox` and its verbatim boxes, they offer a nice interface for 'divided' boxes for presentation of input/output or code/result.

Comment: I assume that the suggested `\newenvironment{cell}` does not work because the environments involved are `verbatim`-like. `verbatim` commands and environments have some restrictions in how they can be used in other commands and also in how you can hide their beginning and end code.

Comment: Your best bet is to use a tcolorbox based solution. Do you really want to have verbatim material in the output?

Comment: Maybe one could add active/command chars in the verbatim environments to put `\nextpart` in there.

Comment: These newenvironments don't make much sense to me in this order. Especially since there seem to be too many closing parentheses in both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to the desired results can be obtained with a `listing and comment` kind of listing from `tcolorbox`.

For non `LaTeX` language listing, the output is not automatic and the `comment` option can be used to enter the supposed result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most, minted]{tcolorbox}

\DeclareTCBListing{pythonexample}{m}{%
    listing and comment,
    listing engine=minted,
    minted style=xcode,
    minted language=Python,
    minted options={linenos, numbersep=3mm},
    sharp corners,
    toprule=0pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt,
    colback=black!30, colframe=red!75!black,
    bicolor, colbacklower=white, colframe=black,
    fontlower=\ttfamily,
    comment={#1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pythonexample}{Hello World!}
print("Hello World!")
\end{pythonexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]